# In DHCPv6 how should client handle when server advertise prefix with T1 is greater than T2

Tags: ipv6, dhcp

As per RFC-3315, 
"If a client receives an IA_NA with T1 greater than T2, and both T1
and T2 are greater than 0, the client discards the IA_NA option and
processes the remainder of the message as though the server had not
included the invalid IA_NA option."

So my question is "will client keep on sending solicit till it receive valid T1-T2 ??" or "Client applies the prefix and calculates it own T1 & T2 ??"

Answer (score 0):

The RFC states specifically that the client must ignite the invalid IA_NA option, so "fixing" the timers is not allowed. It can use the rest of the message though.

Whether it keeps trying to get addresses is up to the client. If a server makes such a basic error then my personal preference would be to not retry too often. The chances of the server suddenly sending valid values are small. Hopefully there is another DHCPv6 server on the LAN that you can use.